# connection among big-M, Lagrangian, Pentalty Method, and Augmented Lagrangian

Tags: optimization, intuition, lagrange-multiplier

In the context of solving linear programs, the big-M method refers to adding additional variables to the problem such that there is, as far as I understand it, a trivial basic feasible solution. In order to ensure that a feasible solution to this new problem corresponds to a feasible solution of the original problem, the terms $M\cdot auxvar_i$ are added to the objective, with a really large $M$. This can be implemented by using a lexicographic numbering system $Mx>y$ for all $x,y$, or $M$ can actually just be chosen, barring numerical issues, such that it is large enough.

It seems, then, that with LPs, you can drive variables to zero by choosing some large but finite multiplier.

This reminds me of penalty methods for solving constrained optimization problems with unconstrained solvers, except that there is typically limiting behavior. Effectively, you need $M\rightarrow \infty$.

As an example, consider the following constrained minimization:

constrained QP: $\min_x \frac{1}{2}x^2$ subject to $x=1$

One penalty formulation is:

penalty QP: $\min_x \frac{1}{2}x^2 + \frac{1}{2}k(x-1)^2$

which has as a solution $x=\frac{k}{1+k}$.

As $k\rightarrow \infty$,we arrive at the correct answer, but until then there is always some fighting between the objective and the constraint.

It seems like this fighting doesn't happen with linear objectives. Part of my question is understanding why.

The other part of my question is understanding Lagrange multipliers as just the right coefficient to have on soft constraints.  For the constrained quadratic program above, there is a $\lambda$ ($\lambda=-\frac{1}{2}$) such that the following unconstrained problem returns the same answer as the constrained problem:
$\min_x \frac{1}{2}x^2 + \lambda(x-1)$.

The immediate difference between this and the penalty version is that the "soft constraint" is not quadratic. This I can see, but I'm searching for some deeper understanding. For example, it seems like I should be able to get rid of the squaring in the penalty version if I know which way that that the objective is pulling away from the constraint, then I know which sign to give $\lambda$. But this isn't right. Taking $\lambda \rightarrow \infty$ isn't the right thing to do.

Where is the parallel?

Comment: Why do you say "fighting does not happen with linear objectives" (and what is "fighting"?) If you minimize $x$ subject to $x=1$ with the penalty method you get $\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}} [x + k(x-1)^2]$ which gives $x = 1 - 1/(2k)$, which again only is correct as $k\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: The reason why the problem of minimizing $x^2$ subject to $(x-1)^2 \leq 0$ does not have a (finite) Lagrange multiplier, even though both $x^2$ and $(x-1)^2$ are convex, is that the tangent to the  set $\{(a,b) | a=(x-1)^2, b=x^2\}$ is vertical (infinite slope) at the point $(0,1)$ of interest.  Indeed notice that $db/da = (db/dx)/(da/dx) = (2x)/(2(x-1))$ which is $\infty$ when $x=1$.

Comment: With the penalty method, if you do not square $(x-1)$ then, however big we make $\lambda$ (or $k$), we can always go in a direction for $x$ that makes the term very negative, which the minimization likes but which we do not.

Comment: In general, if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are convex over some convex set $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^N$ (for some positive integer $N$), then the set $\{(a,b) | a \geq g(x), b \geq f(x) \: \mbox{ for some $x \in X$}\}$ is convex, and any boundary point $x^*$ of this set has a tangent hyperplane that contains the set on one side (hyperplane separation theorem).  When the hyperplane has finite slope, then that is a Lagrange multiplier for the problem of minimizing $f(x)$ subject to $g(x) \leq g(x^*)$.

Comment: @Michael thanks for the comments. feel free to make an answer.

The reason I say "fighting does not happen with linear objectives" (with linear penalty) is because I'm thinking of the big-$M$ method as a sort of penalty method. It's not exactly, because the penalty term is not squared. But you do choose an $M$ large enough to drive a variable to be zero (it can't go negative because of the non-negativity constraint in the standard form of a linear program).

Comment: I don't understand your second comment mentioning the constraint $(x-1)^2 \leq 0$. Is that in reference to an example in my question or is that your own example? I can sort of understand why the Lagrange multipliers would be wonky. If you tighten the left-hand-side of that constraint, then there is no $x$ that satisfies is

Comment: The constraint $(x-1)^2=0$ is the same as the constraint $(x-1)^2\leq 0$.  If you apply a Lagrange multiplier method to minimizing $(1/2)x^2$ subject to $(1/2)(x-1)^2 \leq 0$ (being indeed convex objective and constraint), you define $\mu \geq 0$ and minimize $(1/2)x^2 + \mu (1/2)(x-1)^2$ over $x \in \mathbb{R}$, which is the same as your minimzation with $k=\mu$.  But no such $\mu$ works. So you ask "why doesn't a Lagrange multiplier $k$ exist?"  And the reason is as I gave, even though the problem is convex, you have infinite slope at the point of interest.